# Al crear un proyecto en Android Studio. Error ...cache.properties (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Quería comentarles mi problema ya que soy un poco nuevo en esto y todavía no entiendo mucho del tema Android Studio. Cada vez que creo un proyecto nuevo en Android Studio tengo el siguiente error, no importa donde guarde el proyecto, ya he probado en cambiar varias carpetas de destino pero no sirve, este es el problema.

```
Error:C:\Users\NICOLAS\.gradle\caches\2.4\scripts\asLocalRepo41_6c5ymcule2hvs0zk7phnqe614\InitScript\initscript\cache.properties
(El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este error para los que tienen la versión en inglés también se muestra como:

> cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

Para solucionarlo ve a :

```
 C:\Users\[Usuario]\.gradle\caches\
```

Elimina los folders `\2.4` y `\2.8` (o los de la versión anterior que tengas instalada)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Reinicia `Android Studio` y simplemente vuelve a sincronizar los archivos Gradle con tu proyecto.

Comment: Hay varias posibles soluciones pero esta es la que a mi me ha funcionado, y recuerda no es opción instalar todo de nuevo como he visto en algunos post =)

Comment: Claro, como habia puesto, al ser nuevo no conozco mucho. Entonces se me mezclan las cosas, Muchas gracias. Me sirvio lo que me dijiste.

Answer (score 1):

El error aún se presenta en versiones recientes y en caso de que la respuesta anterior no funcione, eliminen el archivo `"buildOutputCleanup.lock"` :

```
./<pathProyecto>/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup/buildOutputCleanup.lock
```

Además de las carpetas de versiones.